# Calling Watson Conversation API from behind a Proxy server using Node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using Watson Node.js SDK https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud to send a message to Watson Conversation service, but I'm behind a http proxy and not able to reach to the Watson service. How might we configure proxy details (either inside or outside of Node.js) so that the the outbound API call can be made?

```
var Watson = require( 'watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1' );  // watson sdk

// Create the service wrapper
var conversation = new Watson( {
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>',
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
  version_date: '2016-09-20',
  version: 'v1'
});

conversation.message( payload, function(err, data) {
...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure about this but can you set the environment variable for http_proxy? I believe that this should force the use of the proxy regardless of the what the developer cloud module does.

```
process.env.http_proxy = "https://YOUR_PROXY_HOST:YOUR_PROXY_PORT";
```

**If that works you should set the variable using:**

```
npm set <key> <value>
```

Comment: To add some context, this is because the underlying request library checks for these environment properties. Note that there is a second https_proxy variable for HTTPS. Documentation is at https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables